# Python Replace consecutive letters with different variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, replace, counting

I hopefully have an easy question. I just cant figure out the correct function to use. I want to replace repeating characters with different variables depending on how many times it repeats consecutively.

```
with open("text1.txt","r") as File:

    for line in File:
        Counting = line.count('a')
        if Counting == 1:
            Line1 = line.replace('a', '1')
            print(Line1)
        elif Counting == 2:
            Line1 = line.replace('aa', '2')
            print(Line1)
```

so if 'a' repeats consecutively 3 times I want to replace the 'aaa' with 3 and so on up to 9.The problem is, counting them counts regardless if its consecutive or not. If I read a line 2 characters or three at a time it chops it up. Any ideas or help please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to analyze/replace consecutive groups of letters, then perhaps [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) could be of interest. The example below first extracts all consecutive groups and then checks if the unique element in a particular group is `a`. If so, it replaces this group with the corresponding count of elements, otherwise, it keeps the original input.

```
from itertools import groupby

s = 'aaabaacdd' #test input

ret = ''
for k, v in groupby(s):
    chunk = list(v)
    cnt = len(chunk)

    if k == 'a': #the condition can be extended here, e.g., k == 'a' and cnt <= 9
        #substitute the group of 'a's with something else
        #the substitution can take into account the number of consecutive
        #'a's stored in the variable cnt
        el = '%d' % (cnt)
    else:
        el = ''.join(chunk)
    ret += el
print(ret)
```

produces

```
3b2cdd
```

Comment: I appropriate that , but I did not make my question clear enough. That just counts the amount of 'a'' and puts the length. how could I alter that to put what ever I want as the variable so 'aaa' would be 'Z' instead of 3. It will change.

Comment: @LetsChangeTheWorld then just replace `el = '%d' % (cnt)` with the substitution you want to use, e.g., `el = 'Z'`

Comment: Thank you, explaining that actually helped me understand what the heck all that was doing. I was able to put that into read file pretty quick.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution for a string (one line). You can extend this to read a file.

```
f = 'a b aa b aaa b'
output = f

for i in range(9,0,-1):
    output = output.replace('a' * i, str(i))

print(output)  # 1 b 2 b 3 b
```